# Aura component and LWC are not supporting Nepal locale

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, lightning-inputfield, locale, ui-inputdate

I have a requirement where I need to show date in Nepal locale in both Lightning Web and Aura components. This shows the date in, for example - `२०२१/२/१७` format in Salesforce but on LWC and Aura, it is not supporting this format. It shows the date in for example - `२०२१-०२-१०` format.

In Aura, I have tried with:

1. `ui:inputDate` with format = `yyyy/mm/dd` & `yyyy/m/dd`
2. `lightning:input` where `type="date"`

In LWC, I have tried with lightning-input and Salesforce Internationalization [@salesforce/i18n] to set the date

When I try to save `२०२१-०२-१०` this value as it to the database, Salesforce gives an error of Invalid date.

Can someone suggest what can be done to show the date in Salesforce acceptable format? As per my understanding `ui:input` & `lightining:input` should show date values according to User locale.